# Android AChartEngine - Unable to change textColor of Y-Axis Labels

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

While using AChartEngine (JAR 1.0.0) for Android, I see a method that allows me to change the color of text for X-Axis (`mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK)`)

Unfortunately I am unable to find a corresponding method for the Y-Axis labels!

Also is there a way to set the color of the actual line graph?

I also tried to align the labels to the left of Y-Axis using

```
mRenderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);   
mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
```

but it does seem to function.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is `renderer.setYLabelsColor();` for setting the Y axis label color.

When you use Align.LEFT, it means they are left aligned, if you want to right align them on the left side of the axis, use `Align.RIGHT`.

The line graph color is the one from its own renderer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers Dan! You have been a great help.

Answer (score 2):

To align and set a color properlly you need put it as follow:

```
mRenderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);   
mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 0); 

// setYLabelsColor method you need include which the 
// int for your YLabel, since this library you can 
// use more than one YLabel, so in your case, 
// you only have one YLabel and its index is 0.

mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);  
mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
```